# Proof verification hat $x_n = \{ \sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} - \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1} \}$ is an unbounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

This is the first time i'm proving a sequence is unbounded and have some troubles choosing the right approach.

> Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \{ \sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} - \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1} \}
> $$
>   Prove $x_n$ is unbounded

Start with $x_n$:

$$
\begin{align}
x_n &= \sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} - \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1} = \\
&= \frac{(\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} - \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1})(\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} + \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1})}{\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} + \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1}} = \\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1})^2 - (\sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1})^2}{\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} + \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1}} \\
&= \frac{2n^3}{\sqrt{n^4 + n^3 +1} + \sqrt{n^4 - n^3 + 1}} = \\
&= \frac{2n}{\sqrt{1 + {1\over n} + {1\over n^4}} + \sqrt{1 - {1\over n} + {1\over n^4}}}
\end{align}
$$

Now consider the denominator:

$$
d_1 =\sqrt{1 + {1\over n} + {1\over n^4}} \\
d_2 = \sqrt{1 - {1\over n} + {1\over n^4}}
$$

$d_1$ is bounded with:
$$
1 < d_1 < \sqrt3
$$

But $d_2$ is also bounded:
$$
0 < d_2 \le 1
$$

Therefore their sum is bounded:

$$
1 < d_1 + d_2 \le 1 + \sqrt3
$$

So finally we have $2n$ is unbounded and $d_1 + d_2$ is bounded. Hence:

$$
2n \over d_1 + d_2
$$

is unbounded.

I'm wondering how is even unboundness proven? Should I use some constant say $M$ and prove that there exist $N > n$ such that $x_N > M$? If so then how could I do it for the given problem. Also i'm interested whether my approach is valid at least in some way because it feels like it's not.

Please note that this is a precalculus question. I know this could be easily solved by showing that the limit does not exist, but I'm not allowed to use calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is entirely correct; by writing $x_n$ as a fraction and showing that the denominator is bounded whereas the numerator is unbounded, you can indeed conclude that the sequence is unbounded.

In general, to show that a sequence is unbounded it suffices to show that for every constant $M$ there exists an integer $N$, depending on $M$, such that $x_N>M$. In this case, to find an $N$ such that
$$x_N=\sqrt{N^4+N^3+1}-\sqrt{N^4-N^3-1}=\frac{2N}{d_1+d_2}>M.$$
You already noted that $d_1+d_2<1+\sqrt{3}$ so you can take any $N$ satisfying
$$N>\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}M.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good so far and in your last paragraph you nearly stated what is left to prove:

The thing is that for **every** $M\in\mathbb{R}$ you need to find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\geq M$ for all $n\geq N$.

Use your lower bound of $x_n$ to find such an index for any given $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is absolutely valid.

You have proved that $$x_n=\frac{2n}{d_1+d_2} \ge \frac{2n}{1+\sqrt{3}} \gt \frac{n}{2} $$

So for any given $M \gt 0$, you can choose $N = 2M$, s.t. $x_N \gt M$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: assume $\alpha>\beta>0$ and consider that
$$ \sqrt{\alpha}-\sqrt{\beta} = \int_{\beta}^{\alpha}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2\sqrt{\gamma}},\qquad \gamma\in(\beta,\alpha). $$
If $\alpha=n^4+n^3+1$ and $\beta=n^4-n^3+1$ we get
$$\sqrt{n^4+n^3+1}-\sqrt{n^4-n^3+1} = \frac{n^3}{\sqrt{n^4+O(n^3)}} = n+O(1) $$
hence the given sequence is clearly divergent.